# strategy.entry at 9am starts one hour late

Tags: pine-script

I wrote this simple code to open a short position at 9am and close it at 10am.

```
//@version=5

strategy(title="DAX Morning", shorttitle="DAX9am")

if hour == 09
    strategy.entry("short", strategy.short, 10)
if hour == 10
    strategy.close_all("close", "Closed position")

plot(hour)
```

If I plot "hour" it gives me the exact time of the respective candles I want to open and close. Perfect!

[image: 1]

Now, if I use "hour" in the if-statement:

```
if hour == 09
```

It resolves as true but opens the position one hour later at 10am?

[image: 2]

Can anybody explain to me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A backtest will always open the position one candle later so if you're on a H1 chart, your 9h signal will be executed at the 9 am candle close aka at 10 am candle open